# Python :0 being appended to string

Tags: python, string, tensorflow, tensorboard, tensor

I am trying to print the name of a layer in tensorflow using this code.

```
 ## Creating the convolutional layer
    layer = tf.nn.conv2d(input=input,
                     filter=weights,
                     strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                     padding='SAME')

 print("layer name is", str(layer.name))
```

The output is 'Conv2D:0'.

In tensorboard its name is displayed as Conv2D.

Why is the :0 being appended to the name? Or is this the actual name?

Comment: Apparently it is the actual name. Try `str(layer.name).rpartition(':')[0]`

Comment: @Willem could I ask how you determined it was the actual name? Thank you

Comment: Python's `print` does not lie ;)

Comment: haha made me laugh